# Jquery mouseover and click not working on same element

Tags: jquery

I have this code , mouseover is working fine but click event is not working

HTML CODE:

```
<span class="rating">
<span class="rating1 rate" data-rating="1"  title="1"><i class="icon-star-empty" ></i>        </span>
<span class="rating2 rate" data-rating="2" title="2"><i class="icon-star-empty"  ></i></span>
<span class="rating3 rate" data-rating="3" title="3"><i class="icon-star-empty"  ></i></span>
<span class="rating4 rate" data-rating="4" title="4"><i class="icon-star-empty"  ></i></span>
<span class="rating5 rate" data-rating="5" title="5"><i class="icon-star-empty"  ></i></span>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.rate', function () {
   var rating = parseInt($(this).attr('data-rating'), 10);
   var rate = rating + 1;

   for (var j = 1; j < rate; j++) 
      {
       $('.rating' + j).html('<i class="icon-star" title="' + j + '" data-rating="' + j + '"></i>');
      }

   for (var i = rate; i < 6; i++) 
      {
       $('.rating' + i).html('<i class="icon-star-empty" title="' + i + '" data-rating="' + i + '"></i>');
      }
    });


$(document).on('click', '.rate', function () {
  var rate = parseInt($(this).attr('data-rating'), 10);
  alert(rate);
 });
```

JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/EnjCH/1/

Comment: @SRy are you sure about that? The two events can coexist on the same element...

Comment: Not sure whats not working...   I went to the jsfiddle and it seems all good...

Comment: @buzzsawddog In Js fiddle Try clicking the star. alert is not firing

Comment: @Manish It is for me...

Comment: Okay So I tried in IE9 and Chrome and it does not work.  Originally I tried in FF and it did work.  My Chrome and FF are up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$('.rate').on('mouseenter', function () {
    var rating = parseInt($(this).attr('data-rating'), 10),
        rate = rating + 1, $rates = $('.rate');
    $rates.find('.icon-star').removeClass('icon-star').addClass('icon-star-empty');
    $rates.filter(':lt(' + ($rates.index(this) + 1) + ')').find('i').removeClass('icon-star-empty').addClass('icon-star ');

});


$('.rate').on('click', function () {
    var rate = parseInt($(this).attr('data-rating'), 10);
    alert(rate);
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nPL7/)**

Your issue could be because on mouse over you keep on changing the html and mouse over probably gets triggered over and again and there is no click event gets triggered as the elements which it is over(`i`) gets changed over and again so your event is lost(click/mouseover actually happens on `i` which gets bubbled up to the span's handlers). So instead just add/remove class which is what you just want.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

```
$('.rate').on('mouseover', function () {
    console.log('in mouseover');
});


$('.rate').on('click', function () {
    alert('in click');
});
```

I'd suggest to keep things simple and first make sure you wired up the event handlers properly. Only then would I add logic since that can complicate things. Take it from the sample above and make sure that works in your application. If so, you can start adding logic to it

Comment: Both events are working fine if i remove the for loop. Check the fiddle click event is not working